# How to suspense the whole component before the image inside is loaded?

Tags: reactjs, image, preload, react-suspense

I have the following component:
In this component, there is an image.
When I load the page, I realize the page will be loaded first then the image will be loaded later. How can I suspense the whole page before the image is loaded?
I have tried to wrap the whole div (id="container") in a Suspense component with a fallback method but it doesn't seem to work on images, and only on components.

How can I suspense the whole component before the image inside is loaded?

```
import React from "react";
import resume from "../assets/Joe_Rogan_Resume.jpg";
import Banner from "./Banner";

const Resume = () => (
  <div id="container">
    <Banner styleclass="ResumePageBanner" h1text="My Resume" />
    <div className="resumePage">
      <div id="resume">
        <img src={resume} alt="Resume" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Resume;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Suspense` component in React 16.x only lets you wait for some code to load, not any type of data (including images). `Suspense` for data fetching is still experimental. So you need to handle it manually if you don't want to use an unstable version.

```
import React from "react";
import resume from "../assets/Joe_Rogan_Resume.jpg";
import Banner from "./Banner";

const Resume = () => {
  const [isImageLoaded, setIsImageLoaded] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => setIsImageLoaded(true);
    image.src = resume;

    return () => {
      image.onload = null;
    };
  }, []);

  if (!isImageLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div id="container">
      <Banner styleclass="ResumePageBanner" h1text="My Resume" />
      <div className="resumePage">
        <div id="resume">
          <img src={resume} alt="Resume" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Resume;
```